# How to handle client cancel request in Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Controller with a method mapped with @RequestMapping and it returns an object is JSON format so it also has @ResponseBody. Part of getting the object that it should return is a wait() on an object, in a producer/consumer type of situation.

The client can of course cancel their request any time, but I want to be able to interrupt that wait() command the controller is doing when the client cancels. Currently the ajax request throws a client side error with statusType timeout and I can handle it on the client side. But it seems to still leave a thread waiting on the server side which I want to cleanup.

But how?

I seem to recall getting Socket Closed type of errors in older web apps, I dont see that happening with this Spring 3 app on WebLogic 10.3

I see logging like this when the client request is cancelled while the controller is sitting on a wait():

"  <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "623" seconds working on the request etc..."

Comment: I think this comes back to the underlying webserver impl and how it handles cancelled/stopped requests.  Most server's I'va had experience with  will detect a "Broken Pipe" when the server tries to write to response.  Perhaps try waiting some period, writting something trivial (e.g. whitespace) to response and then waiting again?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to surround your controller logic in a try/catch and try to kill the thread within the catch block.